# Referencing non-exportable file in node module

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, scope

I am trying to reference an html document in a "self containing" module. The module is comprised of two files:

```
app_root/node_module/my_module/main.js
app_root/node_module/my_module/header.html
```

main.js contains:

```
module.exports.test = function() {
   var doc = fs.readFileSync('./header.html');
   console.log(doc);
}
```

when i run my program in `app_root/program.js`

```
require('my_module').test();
```

When i start my app, the current working directory is set to `app_root`. When it tries to read `./header.html` it breaks because the paths aren't correct.

How would I find directory of the installed module without knowing anything about what is running it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) to refer to the path of the current script.

So `main.js` would become:

```
module.exports.test = function() {
  var doc = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/header.html');
  console.log(doc);
}
```

Comment: I rewrote the question since i don't think it correctly reflected what i am trying to do.